# is it mandatory to configure the allow in chrony.conf

Tags: linux, rhel, time, ntp, chrony

according to the redhat document - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-understanding_chrony_and-its_configuration

```
allow
Optionally specify a host, subnet, or network from which to allow NTP connections to a machine acting as NTP server. The default is not to allow connections.
Examples:

allow 192.0.2.0/24
```

the default in `chrony.conf` is

```
# Allow NTP client access from local network.
#allow 192.168/16
```

is it mandatory to set the "allow" with the specific network?

I just mentioned this , because `chrony` service on our tests machines not synchronize to the `NTP server` ,

but after we configured the "allow" in `chrony.conf` , chrony service work properly and sync well to NTP server

is it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your formulation, I didn't completely understand *where* you have added the `allow` directive in order to make the service work as expected.

To quote from the `chrony.conf(5)` man page:

> allow [all] [subnet]
>
> The allow directive is used to designate a particular subnet from which NTP clients are allowed to access the computer as an NTP server.
>     The default is that no clients are allowed access, *i.e. chronyd operates purely as an NTP client*. If the allow directive is used, chronyd will be both a client of its servers, and a server to other clients.

In other words, on your `chrony` **server**, the `allow` directive is mandatory, whereas on pure NTP **clients**, it is not.

If, therefore you had no `allow` statement in the `chrony.conf` of your NTP *server*, it is expected that no client was able synchronize to that machine. If, on the other hand, you had to add the `allow` directive in the `chrony.conf` of your *client* machines in order to make things work, then you may have a non-standard network configuration which requires this setting or I didn't correctly understand your question.

Comment: just want to clear - we remove the mark from allow with the right network on our chrony clients not chrony server , so after that we see stable sync to NTP server